# Unable to select date from the Calender Control on appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><hierarchy rotation="0"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[18,50][702,1184]"><node index="0" text="Onward Date" resource-id="android:id/alertTitle" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[98,118][622,180]" /><node index="1" text="" resource-id="com.goibibo:id/calendar_view" class="android.widget.ListView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[50,180][670,1024]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,180][638,722]"><node index="0" text="August 2018" resource-id="com.goibibo:id/title" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,212][638,268]" /><node index="1" text="Sun" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,276][161,327]" /><node index="2" text="Mon" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,276][240,327]" /><node index="3" text="Tue" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,276][319,327]" /><node index="4" text="Wed" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,276][399,327]" /><node index="5" text="Thu" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,276][478,327]" /><node index="6" text="Fri" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,276][557,327]" /><node index="7" text="Sat" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,276][637,327]" /><node index="8" text="29" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,327][161,406]" /><node index="9" text="30" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,327][240,406]" /><node index="10" text="31" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,327][319,406]" /><node index="11" text="1" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="true" bounds="[319,327][399,406]" /><node index="12" text="2" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,327][478,406]" /><node index="13" text="3" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,327][557,406]" /><node index="14" text="4" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,327][637,406]" /><node index="15" text="5" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,406][161,485]" /><node index="16" text="6" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,406][240,485]" /><node index="17" text="7" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,406][319,485]" /><node index="18" text="8" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,406][399,485]" /><node index="19" text="9" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,406][478,485]" /><node index="20" text="10" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,406][557,485]" /><node index="21" text="11" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,406][637,485]" /><node index="22" text="12" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,485][161,564]" /><node index="23" text="13" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,485][240,564]" /><node index="24" text="14" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,485][319,564]" /><node index="25" text="15" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,485][399,564]" /><node index="26" text="16" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,485][478,564]" /><node index="27" text="17" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,485][557,564]" /><node index="28" text="18" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,485][637,564]" /><node index="29" text="19" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,564][161,643]" /><node index="30" text="20" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,564][240,643]" /><node index="31" text="21" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,564][319,643]" /><node index="32" text="22" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,564][399,643]" /><node index="33" text="23" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,564][478,643]" /><node index="34" text="24" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,564][557,643]" /><node index="35" text="25" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,564][637,643]" /><node index="36" text="26" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,643][161,722]" /><node index="37" text="27" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,643][240,722]" /><node index="38" text="28" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,643][319,722]" /><node index="39" text="29" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,643][399,722]" /><node index="40" text="30" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,643][478,722]" /><node index="41" text="31" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,643][557,722]" /><node index="42" text="1" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,643][637,722]" /></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,722][638,1024]"><node index="0" text="September 2018" resource-id="com.goibibo:id/title" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,754][638,810]" /><node index="1" text="Sun" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,818][161,869]" /><node index="2" text="Mon" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,818][240,869]" /><node index="3" text="Tue" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,818][319,869]" /><node index="4" text="Wed" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,818][399,869]" /><node index="5" text="Thu" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,818][478,869]" /><node index="6" text="Fri" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,818][557,869]" /><node index="7" text="Sat" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,818][637,869]" /><node index="8" text="26" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,869][161,948]" /><node index="9" text="27" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,869][240,948]" /><node index="10" text="28" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,869][319,948]" /><node index="11" text="29" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,869][399,948]" /><node index="12" text="30" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,869][478,948]" /><node index="13" text="31" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,869][557,948]" /><node index="14" text="1" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,869][637,948]" /><node index="15" text="2" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[82,948][161,1024]" /><node index="16" text="3" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,948][240,1024]" /><node index="17" text="4" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[240,948][319,1024]" /><node index="18" text="5" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[319,948][399,1024]" /><node index="19" text="6" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[399,948][478,1024]" /><node index="20" text="7" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[478,948][557,1024]" /><node index="21" text="8" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[557,948][637,1024]" /></node></node><node index="2" text="Dismiss" resource-id="android:id/button2" class="android.widget.Button" package="com.goibibo" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[474,1040][646,1136]" /></node></hierarchy>
```

Unable to select date from the Calender Control on appium. See the screenshot of the calender control for more info[image]

Comment: Please share screenshot of your Inspector

Comment: Added the device screenshot. Please check and help